# Display Content Underscore js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display all my data within a table using Underscore.js.

I have a div container class here:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Now on windows load I added an event Listener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
      let content = document.getElementById('container');
      _.each(students, function(elem, index, list){
        _.extend(elem, {overall_score : (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2});
        let items = '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>School</th><th>Grade</th><th>Overall Score</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="studentRec"><td class="lastname">' + elem.lastname +
        '</td><td class="firstname">' + elem.firstname + '</td><td class="school">' + elem.school + '</td><td class="grade">' + elem.grade + '</td><td class="overall-score">' + elem.overall_score + '</td></tr></tbody>';
        content.innerHTML += items;
      });
    });
```

So basically I added all of my records in the items variable and put them within the table layout. I also extended a specific column w/c is overall score. Now instead of a plain table, I got this:

[image]

As you can see the table header gets repeated each time. What do you think am I missing here to create a perfect table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you output many table for each record...

try this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    let content = document.getElementById('container');
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    let thead = document.createElement('thead');
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    let tr;
    thead.innerHTML = '<tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>School</th><th>Grade</th><th>Overall Score</th></tr>';

    _.each(students, function(elem, index, list){
        _.extend(elem, {overall_score : (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2});
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.className = 'studentRec';
        tr.innerHTML = '<td class="lastname">' + elem.lastname +
        '</td><td class="firstname">' + elem.firstname + '</td><td class="school">' + elem.school + '</td><td class="grade">' + elem.grade + '</td><td class="overall-score">' + elem.overall_score + '</td>';
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    });

    table.border = 1;
    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    content.appendChild(table);
});
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, lose <tbody>, try again

Comment: It seems like you appended a lot there? :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have written the part of `<table><thead> ... </thead>` under the `_.each`, every element in the array creates a *new* table. The solution is to pull out the `<table><thead> ... </thead>` from the iteration, and then there would be one table, with one row each for every element in the array.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
  let content = document.getElementById('container');
  var tableBody = "";
  tableBody += '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>School</th><th>Grade</th><th>Overall Score</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

  _.each(students, function(elem, index, list){
    _.extend(elem, {overall_score : (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2});
    let items = '<tr class="studentRec"><td class="lastname">' + elem.lastname +
    '</td><td class="firstname">' + elem.firstname + '</td><td class="school">' + elem.school + '</td><td class="grade">' + elem.grade + '</td><td class="overall-score">' + elem.overall_score + '</td></tr>';
    tableBody += items;
  });

  tableBody += '</tbody></table>';
  content.innerHTML += tableBody;
});
```

Comment: Can you try now? I am suspecting that with the previous version, the browser might have been filling into the gaps that we leave behind.

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating the header inside your loop, try appending rows directly to your table :

```js
var students = [{
  firstname: 'Harry',
  lastname: 'Potter',
  school: 'Poudlard',
  grade: '1st',
  midterm_score: 100,
  final_score: 100
}, {
  firstname: 'Harry',
  lastname: 'Potter',
  school: 'Poudlard',
  grade: '1st',
  midterm_score: 100,
  final_score: 100
}, {
  firstname: 'Harry',
  lastname: 'Potter',
  school: 'Poudlard',
  grade: '1st',
  midterm_score: 100,
  final_score: 100
}, {
  firstname: 'Harry',
  lastname: 'Potter',
  school: 'Poudlard',
  grade: '1st',
  midterm_score: 100,
  final_score: 100
}];

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  let content = document.getElementById('list');
  _.each(students, function(elem, index, list) {
    _.extend(elem, {
      overall_score: (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2
    });
    let items = '<tr class="studentRec"><td class="lastname">' + elem.lastname +
      '</td><td class="firstname">' + elem.firstname + '</td><td class="school">' + elem.school + '</td><td class="grade">' + elem.grade + '</td><td class="overall-score">' + elem.overall_score + '</td></tr>';
    content.innerHTML += items;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>Overall Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```